# Countering Fuckip IP Anonymity FireFox Addon

Tags: firefox, nginx, firefox-addon

http://ipfuck.paulds.fr/

We've been recently getting hammered by this Firefox plug-in. It sends a fake IP in the headers so when our nginx web server picks up the IP it is a fake one.

Is there any way to get a real IP address or block out requests that have this plug-in installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is actually no client IP entries in any HTTP Headers. There are only some un-official proxy headers which are added to a request, so that a proxy server can tell you the real ip of the connecting client (since the tcp socket will only reveal the IP address of the proxy server).

The plugin you linked to adds those proxy headers, to "fake" a proxy request, by adding a `X-Real-IP: 1.2.3.4` or `X-Forwarded-For: 1.2.3.4` header to the request. But no one forces you to use that IP address (which can be fake, like the `1.2.3.4` example here), you can always use the IP address of the socket that initiated the connection - which will be the client's real IP address if he uses the mentioned plugin.

Within the `location` section of your nginx configuration, you get the socket IP address through the `$remote_addr` variable. To retrieve the "fake" IP address, you can use `$http_x_forwarded_for` or `$http_x_real_ip` variable.

If you are using any application/cgi backend, you usually can examine the full headers and the socket IP address (i.e. in PHP you should check `$_REQUEST` and `$_HEADERS` variables)